# Let $a_1, a_2, a_3,\dotsc$ be the sequence $1/4, 1/8, 1/16,\dotsc$ Find $n$ such that $a_{30} = 2^n$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $a_1, a_2, a_3,\dotsc$ be the sequence $1/4, 1/8, 1/16,\dotsc$ Find $n$ such that $a_{30} = 2^n$.

I solved it using the formula $u_n = u_1 r^{n-1}$

$$
u_{30} = \frac{1}{4}\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)^{29}
$$
I got the correct answer but I'm not sure how to do it the other way in order to find $n$ as the question asks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a_1 = \frac 14 = 2^{-(1+1)}, a_2 = \frac 18 = 2^{-(2+1)}, a_3 = \frac 1{16}= 2^{-(3+1)}$, then doesn't it stand to reason that $a_{30}= 2^{-(30+1)} = 2^{-31}$, giving $n=-31$?

There's nothing wrong with your method either. Just finish up by noting that $\frac 14 (\frac 12)^{29} = 2^{-2}\cdot 2^{-29} = 2^{-31}$, giving you the same answer as the above.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! But what formula is that?

Comment: It's just pattern spotting. An elementary, but universally useful tool in Math.

Comment: @aryamank Just in case your confusion was in finding $n$ using your method (applying the geometric progression formula), I edited my answer to cover that.

Answer (score 0):

$a_n=2^{(-n-1)}$
This is the general term.
Just replace $n$ by $30$.

Comment: The general term of what?

Comment: The general term of your sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You have $$ 2^{-2}, 2^{-3},...,2^{-n-1},...$$

The $30_{th}$ term is $2^{-31}$